# distanceFromLocation - Calculate distance between two points

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Just a quick question on Core Location, I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points, code is below:

```
    -(void)locationChange:(CLLocation *)newLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {   

    // Configure the new event with information from the location.
        CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = [newLocation coordinate];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D oldCoordinate = [oldLocation coordinate];

        CLLocationDistance kilometers = [newCoordinate distanceFromLocation:oldCoordinate] / 1000; // Error ocurring here.
        CLLocationDistance meters = [newCoordinate distanceFromLocation:oldCoordinate]; // Error ocurring here.
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the last two lines:

> error: cannot convert to a pointer type

I've been searching Google, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
```

The method you're trying to use is a method on a [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation) object :)

Comment: and also keep in my mind "This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth" apple documents. So this won't give the distance via road.

Comment: how can find distance via road ? @deanWombourne

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava how can i find the distance via road

Comment: The easiest way would be to ask a question on stack overflow ;) Google have an API that you can use (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and so do Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html) I guess because you're asking this on an iOS question you'll probably want the Apple one :)

Comment: Good Answer, but in iOS9 this code function is taking more time than iOS8. do you have any idea how to fix?

Comment: @CodeHunterr That sounds strange - how much slower is it running?

Comment: Here is time statistics: when open 200 locations it will take 2 seconds to sort all the location according to distance in iOS 8...but when you open same contacts on iOS9 it will take min 12+ seconds to sorting all the locations according to distance.

Comment: The problem might be how you are sorting your points - do you calculate the distance between each point before you sort, or do you calculate it each time you compare two points?

Comment: Can you ask a question on stack overflow with your sorting code so we can see what's going on? Thanks! If you put the link in this question's comments I can take a look :)

Answer (score 22):

The distance is calculated between 2 CLLocations and not between to coordinates.

You need to use these coordinates to get the CLLocations for the respective coordinates using the following line of code

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate: newCoordinate altitude:1 horizontalAccuracy:1 verticalAccuracy:-1 timestamp:nil];
```

Similarly for the other coordinate and then you can calculate the distance between these two locations using the following line of code

```
CLLocationDistance kilometers = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation] / 1000;
```

Hope this will help you.

**Update:** Swift 3.0

```
let distanceKiloMeters = (newLocation.distance(from: oldLocation))/1000
```

Answer (score 11):

**In Swift**

Let's create a method function that calculates distance between two locations:

```
 func distanceBetweenTwoLocations(source:CLLocation,destination:CLLocation) -> Double{

        var distanceMeters = source.distanceFromLocation(destination)
        var distanceKM = distanceMeters / 1000
        let roundedTwoDigit = distanceKM.roundedTwoDigit
        return roundedTwoDigit

    }
```

If you want only two digits:

```
extension Double{

    var roundedTwoDigit:Double{

        return Double(round(100*self)/100)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer. Just a minor point. You should replace `var` with `let` iniside distanceBetweenTwoLocations func ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to do with 2 CLLocationCoordinate2D values then you can use this.

This is Swift 2.1 on Xcode 7.1

```
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    func distanceInMetersFrom(otherCoord : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let firstLoc = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        let secondLoc = CLLocation(latitude: otherCoord.latitude, longitude: otherCoord.longitude)
        return firstLoc.distanceFromLocation(secondLoc)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you're calling an object [method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a):

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location;
```

of class CLLocation.

CLLocationCoordinate2D is in fact a structure, consisting of two doubles:

```
typedef struct
{
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

Proper way of doing this is to get a `CLLocation` object and call `distanceFromLocation` on it. Like this:

```
CLLocation* newLocation;
CLLocation* oldLocation;
CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
```

Of course you first need to initialize both of those values (from `CLLocationManager`, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:"Value" longitude:"Value"];

CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:"Value" longitude:"Value"];

CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"distance:-%f",distance);//distance in Miter
```

Comment: Need explanation for this answer

Comment: Hi  Burhanuddin Rashid This is not Android Development code. it is ios Development code for the "Calculate distance between two points"

Comment: It doesn't matter weather its IOS,Android or any other Technical Field. The Think is answer should have little bit explanation with the code...just don't copy paste the code..please have courtesy for some explaination

Comment: Hi Burhanuddin Rashid this answer is not copy and past. it is apple default function to get Distance. 
my answer is little but its work perfectly.
you enter  locA enter Lat,long
locB enter Lat,long 
to Calculate  distance in LocA to LocB.
More information[link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager)
thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the excellent libary [CoreLocation utitlities](https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils) :

```
- (CLLocationDistance) distanceFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) fromCoord;
{
    double earthRadius = 6371.01; // Earth's radius in Kilometers

    // Get the difference between our two points then convert the difference into radians
    double nDLat = (fromCoord.latitude - self.coordinate.latitude) * kDegreesToRadians;  
    double nDLon = (fromCoord.longitude - self.coordinate.longitude) * kDegreesToRadians; 

    double fromLat =  self.coordinate.latitude * kDegreesToRadians;
    double toLat =  fromCoord.latitude * kDegreesToRadians;

    double nA = pow ( sin(nDLat/2), 2 ) + cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow ( sin(nDLon/2), 2 );

    double nC = 2 * atan2( sqrt(nA), sqrt( 1 - nA ));
    double nD = earthRadius * nC;

    return nD * 1000; // Return our calculated distance in meters
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious, this is [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)