# iPhone sdk MapDistance

Tags: iphone

Can anyone help me "How to calculate distance between two places in MAP(CLLocation).Tell the delegates,methods etc to be used .

Thanks in advance,

BrightRaj

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

[distanceFromLocation - Calculate distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in `CLLocation` that takes another CLLocation object and returns the distance in meters:

`- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location`

Be aware that it's available only in iOS ≥3.2. If you wanna target older iOS versions, use

`- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location`

This method is marked as deprecated and will disappear at some time in the future.