# iPhone: calculate distance while walking using GPS

Tags: iphone, xcode, gps, distance

I want to calculate the distance that users cover while walking using GPS. For example a user taps the start button and starts to walk or run than when he done he taps stop. What will be the minimum distance user has to travel to get the different lat long?

How can we do it in IPhone, asume we take Lat, long after every 0.3 sec than in the last we have a list of points?

Comment: Calculating distances between gps locations is easy. Everything else is very hard. Especially if you want to track distances at slow speeds. If you measure often you accumulate more error. If you move slow you accumulate more error per distance. Get a [surveyor's wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveyor's_wheel) and test your algorithms in the real world. You'll wonder how erroneous GPS is.

Comment: The most important part of the question (for ma at least..) still remains unanswered : "What will be the minimum distance user has to travel to get the different lat long?" In other words, if I take one or two steps forward will the GPS acknowledge this displacement and calculate the distance travelled (even if it is less than, let's say, 1-1,5 meters) ?

Answer (score 3):

<s>You could do this by calculating the distance between 2 points (latitude, longitude):</s>

(I haven't tested it):

```
-(double)distanceBetweenCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c1 andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2 {
    double long1 = degreesToRadians(c1.longitude);
    double lat1 = degreesToRadians(90 - c1.latitude);

    double long2 = degreesToRadians(c2.longitude);
    double lat2 = degreesToRadians(90 - c2.latitude);

    double gamma = fabs(long1 - long2);
    if (gamma > M_PI) {
        gamma = 2 * M_PI - gamma;
    }    

    double result = cos(lat2) * cos(lat1) + sin(lat2) * sin(lat1) * cos(gamma);
    return acos(result) * 6366.1977; // Kilometers
};

CGFloat degreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
};
```

**UPDATE:** Use [distanceFromLocation - Calculate distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905923/696440) instead

Comment: Or just use the CLLocation method - (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location

Comment: Better approach :p Not had much experience with CoreLocation or MapKit frameworks. So I 'fished' from my old php function pool.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is "straight-line" distance (as the bird flies) and not total distance traveled.