# How we can get distance between two places's coordinate in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app based on google map.where I am measuring distance between two places. so I have tried to find distance between two place coordinate by predefined method "getDistanceFrom" and tried with googleDirectionAPi. 
if I use predefine method I did not get correct distance. 
if I use googleDirectionApi sometimes I did not get response.

so please suggest me solution where I can find response on every hit of api and will able to get distance between two place?

Comment: Can you add an example that includes the types involved?
Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077425/finding-distance-between-cllocationcoordinate2d-points) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: Do you want the distance in a straight line or the driving/travelling distance?

Comment: Their are Two types of Distance Linear Distance using Formula of Latlong and Path Distance. Linear is Free...Path is chargable from Google API.

Comment: @ToineHeuvelmans thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily get the distance between two locations using `CoreLocation`.

The documentation for `CLLocation` shows this... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation#

You can create a `CLLocation` like...

```
CLLocation* location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1]
```

Once you have two locations you can find the distance with...

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 distanceFromLocation: location2];
```

Note, the documentation shows that `getDistanceFrom` was deprecated in iOS3.2 (about 8 years ago) so don't use that.

(Forgive any errors in syntax, it has been a few years since I wrote any Objective-C) :D

Comment: Thanks, but it will provide direct distance between two places. i am using GoogleDirectionApi for correct data of distance where sometimes i am not getting distance or invalid request

Comment: @manoj then I suggest answering the comments under your question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use these coordinates to get the CLLocations for the respective coordinates using the following line of code

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];
NSLog(@"Distance i meters: %f", [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]);
```

Comment: Add some explanation, please.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a HTTP request, call the folowing URL, and it will return the distance between two points.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY

To get the API Key go to the google developer console.

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is not providing data sometime, i have tried with full address of source and destination coordinate and name